# Как получить предсказание бинарной регресии в R

Tags: r

У меня есть такая таблица с данными:

```
0   1
0   1
1   0
0   1
0   1
1   0
0   1
0   1
0   1
1   0
0   1
1   0
1   0
0   1
1   0
0   1
```

Я пытаюсь подсчитать бинарную регрессиию

```
    eelModel1 <- glm( table$V1 ~ table$V2, data = table, family = binomial())
    predict(eelModel1)

        1         2         3         4         5         6         7         8 
-25.56607 -25.56607  25.56607 -25.56607 -25.56607  25.56607 -25.56607 -25.56607 
        9        10        11        12        13        14        15        16 
-25.56607  25.56607 -25.56607  25.56607  25.56607 -25.56607  25.56607 -25.56607
```

Как мне узнать какое значение было апроксимировано? для первого стобца? Если он выводит только то что я и так знаю?

Answer (score 1):

У метода `predict` есть аргумент `type`, который определяет тип предсказанного значения. По умолчанию для `predict.glm` `response` равен `link`. Для получения вероятности наступления события нужно указать `type = "repsonse"`. Бинаризовать вероятность можно путём сравнения полученной вероятности с каким-либо заданным порогом отсечения (cutoff или threshold).

Пример кода для получения желаемого результата:

```
predict(eelModel1, type = "response") >= 0.5
```